# Use "onBackPressed"

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog, void, onbackpressed

I have this code:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit ?");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
        }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

How can I turn back in webview if the button is pressed one time and show the dialog if pressed two times ?

Comment: What is "WebView" ?

Comment: This: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I mean there is no Webview  in your code, So what do you mean by "turn back in webview" ? What is this webview you talk about ?

Comment: This is a part of my code, is not the all code

Comment: Mean if user press back 1 time then you want go back and if he press back 2 time app should ask to exit?

Comment: @Pietroos I know it's part of your code but how did you expect us to understand where to go back if you don't explain it ? Where is your webview on this activity or on a previous one ? What is open "in front" of your webview if you want to "go back " to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
boolean backPressed = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (backPressed) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //Show your Dialog here
    }

    this.backPressed = true;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            backPressed = false;                       
        }
    }, /* Delay between successive presses here*/);
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code, not is not working the back button

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a boolean to know if your dialog is currently showing or not. It's the easiest and cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention a WebView, you could consider this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        // show dialog as before
    }
}
```

This way you go back in the webview as often as needed, then show the dialog when reach the first page.